# Boltzmann machine probability of neuron flipping proof

Tags: proof-writing, neural-networks

I'm trying to prove the following property of a Boltzmann machine. Let $x_i$ be $1$ or $-1,$ and $\Delta E_i$ be the energy change resulting from the flip:

$$P(x_i \to -x_i) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp\left(\frac{\Delta E_i} T \right)}$$

I've tried modifying the derivation in the "Probability of a unit's state" section of this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_machine (the derivation is for something similar).

How does one represent $P(x_i \to -x_i)$ in terms of $P(x_i)$ and $P(-x_i)$? Is trying to find this a promising direction to take? If not, what different direction can be taken instead? Please don't answer this with a full proof, just guidance.

UPDATE: Below is the information I've been given:

- For symmetric connections, $E(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_i\sum_j w_{ij}x_ix_j$
- When system is in thermal equilibrium, probability of state x is $P(x) = \frac{1}{Z}exp(-\frac{E(x)}{T})$

  - where $Z = \sum_i exp(-\frac{E_i}{T})$
- I've also been given equations on probability of training samples, but it doesn't seem relevant

Also, I've corrected the original equation. It originally had a denominator of $1 + \exp\left(-\frac{\Delta E_i} T \right)$.

Comment: It is explained there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_machine#Probability_of_a_unit.27s_state ?

Comment: Not really. The link shows a proof that P(xi = 1) is equal to the right hand side of the equation above. I would need to connect P(xi --> -xi) to P(xi = 1) somehow to be able to use Wikipedia's proof.

Comment: "The network is run by repeatedly choosing a unit and setting its state according to the above formula". And the link doesn't show a proof, but instead explain the probabilistic model we are in (so the formula above is "by definition of the Boltzmann machine")

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following

Comment: $P(x_i = 1)$ and $e^{-\Delta E_i/ T}$ and $e^{-(\sum_j w_{ij} s_j+\theta_j)/T}$ are the same thing, that's the probabilistic model we are in. What requires a proof is that when "repeatedly choosing a unit and setting its state according to the above formula" on the long term the log-probability of a state is its so-called "global energy" $E = \sum_{i,j} w_{ij} s_is_j+\sum_i \theta_i s_i$

Comment: No, this is actually a homework problem. I've been asked to prove the equation shown in the question.

Comment: To prove from what ?

Comment: Made an update to the question

Comment: Ok. It seems you are doing what I wrote backward : the probabilistic model you are assuming is a probability for each global state $P(x) = \frac{1}{Z}exp(-\frac{E(x)}{T}), E(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_i\sum_j w_{ij}x_ix_j$ (where $w_{ij}$ are some given constants) and you want to prove that the local probability of $x_i$ switching to $-x_i$ depends only on $\Delta E_i= \sum_j w_{ij}x_j$ see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_machine#Equilibrium_state

Comment: Yes, essentially that's what the proof is about